# Exclude an specific subfolder on Windows Media Player library

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, music

I have the following directory for my public music files:

[image: Public Music Screen Shot]

That `Public Music` directory have at least contains 100 different Artist having each a respective sub-directory. Those music files that is yet to be sorted (e.g. to be finished updating their metadata), are found on the `[Unsorted Music]` sub-directory. What I want is **to exclude this specific sub-directory**.

Online tips said that to do that:

- Delete by *Right Click* > *Delete* the entries you want to remove on the Windows Media Player's browser pane.
- Remove the parent directory on the library, but the consequence is to add each Artist's folders one by one excluding the specific directory to exclude, either via the Library browser, or on the Windows Media Player Library Manager itself:

  [image: Windows Media Player Library Manager]

And both of that is quite troublesome: I have at least 100 folders after all. Are there any other more convenient alternative to exclude that `[Unsorted Music]` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to exclude specific folders from the library. However you could create a new folder next to `[Unsorted Music]`, something like `[Sorted Music]`. Then move your artist folders to `[Sorted Music]` and only add the `[Sorted Music]` folder as a library location.

Comment: This is excatly what my Setup now, though, I'm thinking of some alternative. Thanks.