# Windows Media Player 12 keeps adding removed folder to library

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-media-player, onedrive

I have a folder of FLAC files on my OneDrive. I go to "Organize > Manage libraries > Music" and remove the folder. However, the next time I log in and open Windows Media Player it is scanning that folder again and I have to remove it again. How do you get Windows Media Player to permanently ignore a folder?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude an specific subfolder on Windows Media Player library](https://superuser.com/questions/989531/exclude-an-specific-subfolder-on-windows-media-player-library)

Comment: Not a dupe. In the question you linked the OP had a folder INSIDE a folder that was getting scanned that he wanted excluded. That is not my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the same location in Explorer's interface instead. It can be accessed by right-clicking the `Music` folder in Explorer and selecting `Properties`.

If that doesn't permanently remove the location from the Music library, then the Music library itself may have been corrupted. In that case, simply removing the library and restoring it again should fix the corruption, see http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-error-library-ms-is-no-longer-working-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete Music library from Libraries view in explorer.
If it is in use by another program then restart PC and try to quickly delete it after starting windows.
It did work for me.